# How to avoid 'on a non-object in ***' error

Tags: php

I am using simple_html_dom like this

```
$html = new \simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($url);
$html->find('a')
```

then sometims this error happens

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /src/Acme/TopBundle/Command/simple_html_dom.php on line 1146
```

its OK. I think,it might happen that load_file fails to get contents of url;

but,I want to pass throw this error and continue process.

so I changed the script like this .

```
$html = new \simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($url);

if (!$html){
            return null;
}
$html->find('a')
```

but it still returns error and stop.

how can I pass throw this error?

Comment: You dont want to ignore the error! you need to find out why it's happening, otherwise you you'll never parse the file and the script will be useless.

Comment: I don't know simple_html_dom but it's pretty bad behaviour when an object is destroyed by a previous call of one of its methods. Maybe DOMDocument works better for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [is_object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php):

```
$html = new \simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($url);

if (!is_object($html){
            return null;
}
$html->find('a')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a defined check and use the gettype.

```
<?php
require('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = new \simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('http://www.bensoft.com/');
if (defined($html) && gettype($html) == 'object') {
  $html->find('a');
}
?>
```